# rails test database won't wipe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm running rails 3.0.3 and using rspec-rails 2.4.1 with a postgresql database. Whenever I run my RSpec tests, the data remains at the end. Does anyone know how to get rails or rspec to wipe the test environment's data between each use?

Please tell me if there's any further information that could make answering my question easier.

Thanks!
Tristan

Comment: I believe the data is cleared out before you run your tests, not after.

Comment: Hey Cam. Sorry, that's probably right but right now neither is happening.

Answer (score 10):

Install the database_cleaner gem and then add this to your spec_helper.rb.

```
Spec::Runner.configure do |config|

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

end
```

Comment: Hey thanks Bobby. Shouldn't the test database start empty everytime you run rspec by default?

Comment: Hey Tristan, it should, but there are weird cases when data lingers around between tests. I also believe if you are using `rake` to invoke your specs it will run a `db:test:prepare` before your specs.

Answer (score 5):

Use transactional examples to rollback the data after every test run

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_examples = true
end
```

Comment: Hi Deepak. I already have that set in my spec_helper file, and my rspec scripts are "require"ing spec_helper.

Comment: I get `undefined method 'use_transactional_examples='` in rspec 2.8.0. Does this method have a new name?

Comment: Yes. its now `use_transactional_fixtures`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any extra gem in order to clean your test DB between runs. In your spec_helper.rb file, configure rspec as follows:

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.around(:each) do |example|
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.transaction do
      example.run
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: this worked for me in Rails 5.1.6 but I had to put it in my rails_helper.rb file, not spec_helper.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, that I just put myself through, is using the wrong `before` block.

I accidentally set a `before` block as an `all` instead of an `each`:

```
before :all do
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  sign_in user
end
```

This caused the `user` to stick around in the database for the entire `rspec` run, which caused validation collisions.

Instead, the `before` should be an `each` so that everything is kept clean through the `rspec` run:

```
before :each do
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  sign_in user
end
```

If you've made this mistake, then you will probably need to manually clean up your test database before things go back to normal. The simplest way to do that is probably to truncate each of the tables (aside from `schema_migrations`).